# How do identify stored procedure containing dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

What is the best way to identify stored procedures that contains dynamic SQL? I created this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.sql_modules  
WHERE 
    REPLACE(definition,' ','') LIKE '%exec(%' 
    OR definition LIKE '%sp_executesql%' 
    OR REPLACE(definition,' ','') LIKE '%execute(%'
```

Will it find all instances?

Comment: As long as your dynamic SQL always begins with exec( execute( or sp_executeSql then I don't see why it wouldn't work, try it. I probably wouldn't bother with the "REPLACE(definition, ' ', '')" though as it seems like you're making it work harder than it needs to

Comment: You can get some false positives this way, but I guess its unavoidable without parsing SQL.

Comment: Your query seems to take care of the most common situations where you'd call/execute dynamic SQL. I think your query is correct. The following links [**1**](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/) and [**2**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) can be used for reference.

Comment: @ChristianBarron I do it because can not be sure how the code is written. It can be "exec('select ...')" or "exec ('select ...')" or even "exec    ('select ...')"

Comment: @KubaWyrostek I can live with false positives. But need to find all instances

Answer (score 1):

I cannot provide you with exact examples, but I can probably point you into right directions. There are Microsoft's classes that are responsible for parsing and generation of SQL batches. You can probably use those classes to parse content of stored procedures and look for all possible *real* dynamic sql invocations.

More information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom(v=sql.110).aspx

I am not sure, whether this covers SQL 2008 as well. Sorry about that.

Here's a sample of how to use those classes to remove comments in SQL scripts:

http://michaeljswart.com/2014/04/removing-comments-from-sql/

**EDIT**

There's and older, also Microsoft's solution, to parse SQL statements. Not as powerful, but SQL 2008 compatible. Please check whether this could suit your needs:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser(v=sql.105).aspx